# UWP - Storyboard in DataTemplate ControlStoryboardAction fires only first time

Tags: xaml, binding, storyboard, uwp, behavior

The request is that the row of my ListView blinks when the property SelectedItem of the ViewModel raises change.

This is my code, the problem is that it works only first time. Subsequent changes are ignored.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding SelectedItem}" Value="True">
                <Media:ControlStoryboardAction>
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation
                                To="#009ABF" 
                                Storyboard.TargetName="myGrid" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                AutoReverse="True" 
                                Duration="0:0:1"
                                RepeatBehavior="1x" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </Media:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                </Media:ControlStoryboardAction>
            </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
            Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="0,2,10,0"
            FontSize="16"
            TextAlignment="Left"/>

        <!--OMISSIS-->
    </Grid>
```

SelectedItem code :

```
    public bool SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            this.selectedItem = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `SelectedItem` type?, please, provide cs code

Comment: At first glance, it's just your `RepeatBehavior="1x"` since it's using the same Storyboard for every instance and you have `AutoReverse` set on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i found.

1) Use Completed event of the Storyboard

```
<Storyboard Completed="SelectedItemReset" FillBehavior="Stop">
```

3) Use the GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger to comunicate from CodeBehind and ViewModel the reset of the property SelectedItem

Xaml

```
<ListView>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid x:Name="DataTemplateGrid">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding SelectedItem}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="True">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Play">
                        <Media:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard Completed="SelectedItemReset" FillBehavior="Stop">
                                <ColorAnimation
                                    To="Lime" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="DataTemplateGrid" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                    Duration="0:0:1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </Media:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                    </Media:ControlStoryboardAction>
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <!--OMISSIS-->

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

CodeBehind

```
private void SelectedItemReset(object sender, object e)
{
GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Default.Send<Mvvm.ViewModels.Units.SelectedItemResetMessage>(new Mvvm.ViewModels.Units.SelectedItemResetMessage());
}
```

MVVM Class .ctor

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Default.Register<SelectedItemResetMessage>(this, message =>
    {
        if (this.SelectedItem == true)
            this.SelectedItem = false;
    });
}
```

Note: My DataTemplate was in a separate file and linked to the ListView with the ItemTemplate property, this prevented me from calling the method Completed in CodeBehind.